# Shiny Javascript Change Button Text

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to change the button text of the shiny element and would like to runjs or javascript to do so.  I'm not sure how to identify the id "btnGenerate" when running js.

```
# ui.R
actionLink("btnGenerate", "Generate Data for Export", class="textbutton", style = "height:40px"),
```

```
# server.R
#runjs("var today = new Date(); alert(today);")
updateActionButton(session, "button", label = txt) # doesnt work
```

Comment: Are you matching the same `inputId`?

Comment: `updateActionLink(session, "btnGenerate", label = "new label") `

Comment: @YBS yes that is desired

Comment: When do you like to change it, on click the button? some other actions to trigger? What text do you want to change to? Why do you use `alert`, that's not for change text. Your question is vague, please be more **specific** and **reproducible**.